# module.exports with mongodb query returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, discord.js

I'm creating a module for recording a purchased item on MongoDB using module.exports. This is my first time using this module.exports.

I need to return the results of the updateOne() query because I need to use the modifiedCount information on my main.js. However, the results are returning as undefined. I read that I should either use a callback or promise, with promise being better. How do I exactly do that on my case?

Here's my code from recordPurchase.js module:

```
const recordPurchase = (userid, item, price) => {
    db.collection("users").updateOne({ userid: userid }, { $push: { purchases: { item: item, price: price } } })
        .then((result) => {
            if (result.modifiedCount > 0) {
                console.log("Success");
                return result; //return the updateone information
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error recording purchase: " + err)
        })
}

module.exports = recordPurchase;
```

And here's how I'm calling it on the main.js

```
  if (msg.content === "test") {
    const userid = "12345";
    const item = "Some item name";
    const price = 10;
    const result = recordPurchase(userid, item, price)
    console.log(result); //returns updateone/result information
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const recordPurchase = (userid, item, price) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.collection("users")
            .updateOne({userid: userid}, {$push: {purchases: {item: item, price: price}}})
            .then((result) => {
                if (result.modifiedCount > 0) {
                    resolve(result) // fulfilled
                } else {
                    reject("error") // rejected
                }
            })
            .catch(reject) // rejected
    })
}

module.exports = recordPurchase;
```

```js
const recordPurchase = async (userid, item, price) => {
    try{
        const result = await db.collection("users").updateOne({userid: userid}, {$push: {purchases: {item: item, price: price}}})
        if (result.modifiedCount > 0) {
            return result
        }else{
            return new Error('error')
        }
    }catch (err){
        return err
    }
}
```

Comment: The `new Promise` is not necessary, return the `db.collection` promise and `throw` inside the promise functions to reject.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. However, if you want to process the data before returning the processed result, then you need to follow this approach.

Comment: Any processing can be completed in the `then` callback when the original promise is returned.

Comment: If this function is used in many places, it is more reasonable to handle it in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did "userid" exist when you update? And why return result when `result.modifiedCount > 0`. In your case, db Promise didn't get result,
and/or: maybe result not match your condition `modifiedCount > 0` and return nothing.
To fix, you should add condition when already success, and add async/await to get result first:

```
const recordPurchase = async (userid, item, price) => {
    const result = await db.collection("users")
        .updateOne({ userid: userid }, { $push: { purchases: { item: item, price: price } } });
    if (!result) throw new Error("User not found!");
    console.log("Success and this is result: ", result);
    return result;
} 
module.exports = recordPurchase;
```

In main.js should be:

```
if (msg.content === "test") {
    const userid = "12345";
    const item = "Some item name";
    const price = 10;
    const result = recordPurchase(userid, item, price)
    console.log(result); //returns updateone/result information
    if(result?.modifiedCount > 0){/*Do your stuff if modified count match*/}
}
```